# Azure Mobile Services: Invalid Operation Exception (platform-specific assembly not found)

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I have developed an app on Xamarin.iOS using Azure Mobile Services component, it has been working fine, just today I made some changes and then I started getting this exception. No matter what I do, it still thinks that this .Ext library is missing

> Windows Azure Mobile Services assembly for the current platform was
>   not found. Ensure that the current project references both
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile and the following platform-specific
>   assembly: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.

I have made sure to remove and install the component via Xamarin.Studio, I have also added manual reference to the libraries (with the platform-specific extension) but still no use.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution in [this blog post](http://blog.csainty.com/2013/12/quick-tip-azure-mobile-services-xamarin.html)

Appearantly I missed one line in the set up of the Mobile Services on the mobile, which is:

```
CurrentPlatform.Init();
```

Once I added this line, the problem is gone. It must have been using old dlls before I cleaned up the solution and moved some code around then it started breaking. Adding the line above fixed it for me, and hope it helps somebody else.

Comment: It is not working for me, it says CurrentPlatform.Init(); doesn't exist in current context. Can you help me?

Comment: That means you have not installed the nuget package or you have not imported the right name space

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I add manually the line

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform.Init()
```

in `AppDelegate.cs` then works fine.

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform.Init();
    LoadApplication(new App());
    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```